# Casting int16_t to uint_8t*

Tags: c++, arduino, int, uint8t, uint16

I have a library driven result stored as an int16_t value (and it is a negative, which I can use the absolute value of) and another library function that requires this value a few steps later in the form uin8_t*. How can this be done without using String?

The following code works, but uses dreaded Strings. Is there a way to do this without invoking String or std::string?

```
 void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
      delay(5000);
      String initialVal= String(-fetchInt()); 
      Serial.print("Initial value is: ");Serial.println(initialVal);//prints "76"
      uint8_t medianVal[sizeof(initialVal);
      medianVal.getBytes(medianVal, sizeof(initialVal));
      Serial.print("median value is: ");Serial.println(medianVal);//prints "76"
      uint8_t* finalVal = medianVal;
      Serial.print("final value is: ");Serial.println((char*)finalVal);//prints "76"
      }

    int16_t fetchInt(){
      return -76;
    }
```

So, how can I turn **int16_t** into **uint8_t***?

It has been pointed out in comments below that
 `Serial.println(static_cast<unsigned>(*finalVal));` works, but this solution converts the uint8_t to an unsigned int and the method requires uint8_t*.

I come from Java and the like and it seems crazy that it is so hard to convert an integer to a string.

Comment: That's strange, but if understood correctly - you'd like the absolute value of `firstVal` to be set into `secondVal`, with no regards to its sign (and - given you cast from a 16-bit integer into an 8-bit - with possible loss of data)?

Comment: yes. The number is always under 120, so there is no loss of fidelity.

Comment: you are trying to set a pointer to -76. IS that really what you want. What do you expect to find there?

Comment: I am looking for a pointer to the alphanumeric character of -76, not the integer value. This is the strength of a radio signal being bounced back to the sender as a health check.

Comment: This sounds more like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Be specific: what library, which method.

Comment: @OrbitingEden What is the library function that requires an _uint8_t*_?

Comment: The library is Radiohead. I have found a solution thanks to all of your help. The solution was to change the final call to: `Serial.println(*&medianVal);` This both preserves the uint8_t* format and the original absolute value.

Comment: @OrbitingEden That's pretty much `Serial.println(medianVal)`.

Comment: @OrbitingEden As KIIV implied, that is pointless. `&medianVal` gives you the address where the `uint8_t` is stored. The `*` before returns the value stored at the address returned by `&medianVal`, which makes the `*&` part a no-op in this context.

Comment: @KIIV and @Ted, It would be awesome if you could answer the question with code that compiles and whose return value is "76" and not "L". Using the solutions suggested in this thread consistently results in a uint8_t* value of "L" and not "76" - which is independent of the printed result of `Serial.println(*&medianValue);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer of type `uint8_t` cannot point to an object of type `int16_t`; you need to copy the value of `firstVal`, but therefore you'll need a separate object to take on the value.

```
uint8_t firstValAbs = firstVal >= 0 ? firstVal : -firstVal;
uint8_t* secondVal = &firstValAbs;
```

Note: `uint8_t x = -34` will *not* give you the absolute value of `-34`, i.e. it will not result in `34`. You'll rather get a two's complement of `-34`, i.e. `255-34+1 == 222`.

Comment: This is a great start, but now the numerical value is being converted to a letter (for instance 76 is converted to "L") and there is weirdly a string concatenated from a prior variable labelled "buf". The results convert "-76" to "LHello World!"

Comment: If you have `uint8_t* secondVal;` you shouldn't do `std::cout << secondVal;` since it's not a null terminated string. Everything after the variable will be printed too (and you probablly had "Hello World" there). You need `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(*secondVal)` if you'd like to see the numerical value. Or someone meant to write `std::wcout << L"Hello World"` and put the `L` inside the `"...."`...

Comment: Ted, your answer solved my problem. In my code it looks like: `Serial.println(static_cast<unsigned>(*finalVal));` and now outputs the correct number.

Comment: Sorry, I have to re-open this. `static_cast<unsigned>` converted it to an unsigned int and it no longer is accepted by the method that requires uint8_t* as a passed variable.

Comment: The cast to `unsigned` was merely for printing purposes. If the function wants an `uint8_t*` you should give it `finalVal`.

Comment: Thanks Ted, when I use finalVal, the letter "L" is the product. It seems like I have to convert the int value to a string representing "76". My first approach is going to be to convert the int16_t to a char* using itoa. The second step would be converting the char* to uint8_t*

Answer (score 3):

`int16_t` stores a signed numeric value using 16 bits (-32,768 to 32,767).

`uint8_t` stores an unsigned numeric value using 8 bits (0 to 255).

If you are sure your `int16_t` value fits into an `uint8_t` after changing the sign, you can just assign it:

```
int16_t firstVal = -76;
uint8_t secondVal = -firstVal;
```

Now, if you need a pointer to the second value, you can just create it. You can not point directly to `firstVal` because you need to store the changed value.

```
uint8_t* secondValPointer = &secondVal;
```

This `uint8_t*` may be interpreted as a pointer to a character in your library. Normally, you should use char for this purpose (also 8 bits, but [it is implementation defined if it is signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/218774)). You can cast this pointer to c`har*`, although you need to tell the compiler you want to cast between pointers using reinterpret_cast:

```
char *secondValAsChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(secondValPointer);
```

Now, you can treat this pointer as a pointer to character. For example the following code will print 'L' because ASCII code for L is 76:

```
std::cout << *secondValAsChar << std::endl;
```

However, you must be very careful with this pointer because secondValAsChar is not a null terminated string, so you may not use the old common methods like `strcat`.

Comment: For my output I am using Serial.print(). If I use this on other uint8_t* integer values, it outputs the numerical value and not the ASCII character represented by the octet. I must use uint8_t* and not char* because the library function requires it.  I edited the code for a compilable example.